# How to sort an array of class objects based on date?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array of hashes:

```
@products = {#<ProductProxy:0xb486d148 @pA={"productAvailableDateTs"=>"2013-12-04T23:07:12.592Z", "mPrice"=>, "pStock"=>, "id"=>, "productId"=>, "productDesignerId"=>}>,
#<ProductProxy:0xb4adf304 @pA={"productAvailableDateTs"=>"2013-1-04T23:07:12.592Z", "mPrice"=>, "pStock"=>, "id"=>, "productId"=>, "productDesignerId"=>}>,
#<ProductProxy:0xb4adecec @pA={"productAvailableDateTs"=>"2013-15-03T23:07:12.592Z", "mPrice"=>, "pStock"=>, "id"=>, "productId"=>, "productDesignerId"=>}>,

...
}
```

I want to sort the array based on `productAvailableDateTs` value, in descending order. I tried doing the following:

```
@products = @products.sort_by{ |k| -k['productAvailableDateTs'] }
```

But doing so, I am not able to access the `productAvailableDateTs` field. i tried to print `@products[0]['productAvailableDateTs']`. But it prints `nil`. How can I access the field correctly?

Comment: This is not an array and it doesn't contain hashes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Sorry for the typo, i missed the `,`. it is indeed an array. I've defined it as @products = Array.new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the data to be sorted by the database (assumed that you got that data from active record), you can convert it into an array and then sort it:

```
@products.to_a.sort{ |a,b| b.productAvailableDateTs <=> a.productAvailableDateTs }
```

If it is already an array:

```
@products.sort{ |a,b| b.productAvailableDateTs <=> a.productAvailableDateTs }
```

Edit: missed the order. The order is implemented by changing the first and second parameter.

Comment: I got the data from `solr`. i am using the same array to list products in the view. So I would like to retain the current format.

Comment: When it is already really an array, just skip the call to to_a and it should work as expected.